# Cambiar orden de los elementos HTML segun el tamaño

Tags: html5, css3, mediaqueries, css-grid-layout

veran estoy haciendo una pagina web, y asi es como se ven en escritorio
[image: Pagina web en escritorio]

pero en celular se ve de la siguiente manera.
[image: Pagina web en celular]

Lo que quiero saber es como hacer para que la imagen cuando este en celular se pase directamente abajo del navbar, y el texto abajo de la imagen, estoy usando CSS grid para el posicionamiento de las imagenes.

Comment: Claro, y ¿el código? Trata de subir lo que tienes o al menos la parte que es relevante a tus elementos. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Podrias usar media media queries para definir estilos segun el tamano de la pantalla.

**Para un dispositivo movil**

```
// Estos estilos aplican si el tamaño de la pantalla no es mayor a 600px
@media (max-width: 600px) { 
  p {
    width: 80%; // El parrafo de texto ocupa el 80% del ancho disponible
  }
}
```